# physics and braket packages with different \braket commands

Tags: incompatibility, physics, braket

I am using the `\usepackage{physics}` package and want to write something using bra-ket notation but with a double bar in the middle (physicist's notation in Quantum Chemistry). It can be written as `\braket{0||0}` using the \usepackage{braket} package, however it is much more useful for me to use the {physics} package for the majority of my work. I cannot use the {braket} package as the command \braket is already a command in the {physics} package, and I don't want to tamper previous pages I've written using the `physics` package. So I guess I have 2 questions.

1) Can you write the equation in the picture using the `physics` package? [image: Equation to br written]

2) Is it possible to import both packages but call on the `\braket` command from different packages when I choose? For example, I may want to use the command from the `physics` package for my first equation, but the `braket` package for my second equation.

Comment: I don't have time to work up a proper answer, but here is an idea: Use the `mathtools` package. Look for `\braket`  in the documentation, and learn how to build your own. You can call it whatever you wish.

Comment: You can use `$\mel{ij}{}{jk}$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `physics` package can do this using `matrix element` commands `\matrixel`, or `\mel` for short. The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}

$\mel{ij}{}{kl}$

\end{document}
```

Will produce the desired output. If desired, an additional second argument can be inserted. (It is empty in the example.)

[image]

There are two other forms of the `\mel` command: `\mel*` and `mel**`. The no-star version adjusts the delimiter heights based on the first and third arguments, but not the second. The one-star version does no resizing at all. The two-star version resizes delimiters based on all three arguments. For example, the code

```
$\mel{\rule{2pt}{2ex}}{\rule{2pt}{3ex}}{kl}\quad%
\mel*{\rule{2pt}{2ex}}{\rule{2pt}{3ex}}{kl}\quad%
\mel**{\rule{2pt}{2ex}}{\rule{2pt}{3ex}}{kl}$
```

produces the output:

[image]

Note that there appears to be a spacing inconsistency between the no-star and one-star versions, compared to the two-star version. The difference appears to be exactly a `thinspace`. Consider the following code and its output:

```
H$\mel{ij}{}{kl}$H

H$\mel*{ij}{}{kl}$H

H$\mel**{ij}{}{kl}$H
```

[image]

The spacing on the left and right is equalized by inserting a negative thin space (`\!`) before `\mel` or `\mel*`.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a solution based on `mathtools`, `xparse` and `etoolbox`. The  syntax is `\mybraket{1st argt | 2nd argt |3rd arrgt}`. The separator for arguments is `|`, but it may be changed to, say, a comma or a semi-colon.

This command can take an optional size argument (`\big, \Big`,&c.). Alternatively, the starred version`\mybracket*` adds an implicit `\left \right` pair before the delimiters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{xparse, etoolbox}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\mybraket[1]{\langle}{\rangle}{\braketargs{#1}}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\braketargs}{ >{\SplitArgument{2}{|}}m }
{\braketargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\braketargsaux}{ m m m}%
{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1}{#1\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#2}}%
{\ifblank{#2}{#1\,\delimsize\vert\mkern-1mu\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#3}%
{#1\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#2\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#3}}}%

\begin{document}


\[ \mybraket*{ij}\quad\mybraket[\big]{ij||jk} \quad\mybraket[\big]{ij|\ell|jk}\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I vote also to you +1. Thanks for the help on site Mathematics.